# Activity not found when linking library project?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have an Android application and a library project that I am using together. I am not having any issues using the components of the library project. I am however not able to launch any of the activities inside of my Application. I keep getting a ClassNotFound exception yet the fully qualified name matches exactly in the error message as it is in the source tree.  All activities are defined correctly in the manifest. What would cause me to be able to launch any activity from the library project but not be able to launch an activity inside of the main application?

Comment: post your solution if you had solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being when I tried to launch any Activities that extend MapActivity. I think the problem was that I had defined uses-library in both manifests for the Google maps api. I changed the build target of the library project to be just vanilla Android and removed the uses library call. My main project now targets the Google apis and has the uses library inside its manifest.

I think it might have been screwing up the build path or something and could not find the MapActivity class or something. Not quite sure but those steps solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the activity of library project to your manifeast file.

Actually some of the jar/library file launches activity internally and that must be add in our application.

Comment: No the activity that is not launching is one inside of the main application not the library project.